# How should I check if resultset is empty or null using datastax cassandra driver for java

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

How should I check for an empty resultset using datastax java cassandra driver?

Suppose I'm executing the following query "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mykey=something"

there is a great chance that the query will not be matched. The following code does not work:

```
if (rs != null) 
   rs.one().getString("some_column");
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You were pretty close,  the correct solution is:

```
Row r = rs.one();
if (r != null)
    r.getString("some_column");
```

The driver will always return a result set, whether or not there were any returned results.  The documentation for [one()](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html#one()) states that if no rows were returned rs.one() returns null.

You can also use [getAvailableWithoutFetching()](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html#getAvailableWithoutFetching()) which returns the number of rows in the result set without fetching more rows.  Since pageSize has to be >= 1, you can be assured if there are is at least 1 row this will always return a value greater than 0.

Comment: Why is this better than using `rs.ìsExhausted`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the value of `rs.isExhausted()` in order to determine whether or not there is additional data in the result set...